# Session verification using PHP

Tags: php, session

Is the below code enough to verify that a session exists and is legitimate or should I be cross checking the user_id value with the user_id stored in my database when the user signed up?

```
 //Session exists
if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"]) && $_SESSION["user_id"] != '')
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What if you deleted the user, but he still has the session? Better check against your database.

Comment: it depends how you set sessions! I didnt get your comment @MilanG can you explain please ? deleted users cant login in do they ?

Comment: What exactly is your definition of "and is legitimate"?

Comment: This only checks if an ID is set; it doesn't check if it is legitimate (assuming legitimate means that the ID exists in the database). What are you trying to do with the code?